# Stuck on basic database input/update

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck on something really simple but just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I had everything working fine until i try to add the item "desc" when I put that in the row isn't added or edited in the database. If i take out the "desc" elements, the query works fine.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["author"])){ $j_author = filter_var($_REQUEST["author"],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); }
$reg_date = date("Y-m-d");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_sys_jobs (author, user, name, desc, rego, status) VALUES ('".$j_author."', '".$j_user."', '".$j_name."', '".$j_desc."', '".$reg_date."', '".$j_status."')");
```

Comment: 1. echo your query and put it here 2. `mysql_error()`

Comment: zerkms hits it right on the spot - check your actual input, check for error message.

Comment: I'm getting all the results posted to the query, all variables are correct, and no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`desc` is a keyword in SQL, meaning "descending order", such as in:

```
select keyword, available_for_use
from sql_keywords
where keyword like `d%`
order by keyword DESC
```

If you *must* use it, you need to backtick it:

```
INSERT INTO wp_sys_jobs (author, user, name, `desc`, rego, ...
```

Me, I tend to avoid all that angst by using non-keywords as column names, such as `descr` :-)

Comment: @frankstuner : Accept the answer (any one) if you think answer is CORRECT... This is how stackoverflow works...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to use `INSERT`, which doesn't support the `DESC`, the system is telling you that you are trying to do something wonky. The documentation on how to use an `INSERT` statement can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

To expand a bit, the keyword `DESC` is only really useful when you are doing a fetch. It needs to be paired with the `ORDER BY` keyword.